# Uncaught Error: Property icon is required for fa-icon/fa-duotone-icon components. at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:23598:29

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, font-awesome, karma-webpack, angular-fontawesome

I am running my test case in the project. I am facing below error when test cases are executing. Although they are not breaking my test case but still printing lots of logs in the console.

I am working on Angular v11.

```
Chrome 88.0.4298.0 (Windows 10) ERROR
Uncaught Error: Property icon is required for fa-icon/fa-duotone-icon components.
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:23598:29

Error: Property icon is required for fa-icon/fa-duotone-icon components.
at faWarnIfIconSpecMissing (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/angular-fontawesome.js:97:1)
at FaIconComponent.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/angular-fontawesome.js:234:1)
at FaIconComponent.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:1520:1)
at callHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2583:1)
at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2542:1)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2493:1)
at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9481:1)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10591:1)
at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9490:1)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10591:1)
```

**App.modules**

```js
    import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

**events.component.ts**

    import { faSearch, faSpinner, faCaretDown, faSync } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

    // Font Awesome Icons
    public faSearch = faSearch;
    public faSpinner = faSpinner;
    public faCaretDown = faCaretDown;
    public faRefresh = faSync;
```

**events.component.html**

```html
    <fa-icon *ngIf="searching.searchText" [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon>
```

**Package.json**

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/common": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/core": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/forms": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/router": "11.2.10",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.8.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "0.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
        "@ng-select/ng-option-highlight": "0.0.6",
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "6.1.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "12.1.2",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
        "angular2-uuid": "1.1.1",
        "animate.css": "3.7.2",
        "asn1js": "2.0.26",
        "bootstrap": "3.4.1",
        "bootstrap-vertical-tabs": "1.2.2",
        "chart.js": "2.9.4",
        "core-js": "3.11.1",
        "deep-object-diff": "1.1.0",
        "dragula": "3.7.2",
        "ejs": "3.0.2",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "http-errors": "1.7.3",
        "http-status-codes": "1.4.0",
        "ipaddr.js": "1.9.1",
        "jquery": "3.5.1",
        "lodash": "4.17.20",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "moment-timezone": "0.5.28",
        "ng-busy": "11.0.0",
        "ng2-charts": "2.3.0",
        "ng2-dragula": "2.1.1",
        "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-rc.11",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "5.6.1",
        "ngx-clipboard": "12.3.1",
        "ngx-ui-switch": "6.0.3",
        "number-abbreviate": "2.0.0",
        "pkijs": "2.1.88",
        "postcss": "8.2.13",
        "postcss-url": "8.0.0",
        "pvutils": "1.0.17",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "6.6.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "6.5.5",
        "sta-interface": "file:../common/sta-interface",
        "sta-mock": "file:../common/sta-mock",
        "tslib": "1.10.0",
        "typeahead.js": "0.11.1",
        "uuid": "3.4.0",
        "validator": "13.0.0",
        "version": "0.1.2",
        "zone.js": "0.10.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "8.4.1",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.9",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "11.2.9",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/cli": "11.2.9",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.10",
        "@angular/language-service": "11.2.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.5",
        "@types/chai": "4.2.11",
        "@types/core-js": "2.5.3",
        "@types/cucumber": "4.0.4",
        "@types/dragula": "3.7.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
        "@types/jasmine-jquery": "1.5.33",
        "@types/jquery": "3.3.34",
        "@types/karma-jasmine": "0.0.29",
        "@types/node": "13.11.1",
        "@types/sinon": "9.0.0",
        "@types/typeahead": "0.11.32",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.31.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.31.0",
        "babel-core": "6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
        "chai": "4.2.0",
        "codelyzer": "5.2.0",
        "cucumber": "1.3.0",
        "del-cli": "3.0.0",
        "eslint": "6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jasmine": "4.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "0.5.0",
        "formdata-polyfill": "3.0.19",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0",
        "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.1",
        "karma": "6.3.2",
        "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
        "karma-cucumber-js": "1.0.3",
        "karma-html-reporter": "0.2.7",
        "karma-jasmine": "2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.3",
        "karma-jasmine-jquery-2": "0.1.1",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
        "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.5",
        "karma-sinon": "1.0.5",
        "prettier": "2.2.1",
        "puppeteer": "5.5.0",
        "sinon": "9.0.2",
        "stats-webpack-plugin": "0.7.0",
        "ts-node": "8.8.2",
        "typescript": "4.0.7",
        "webpack": "4.42.1"
      },
```

Let me know if you need any further information from my end.

Comment: The pattern presented in the question should not trigger the presented error. Please create a minimal reproduction and open an issue in https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome if you can show otherwise. This error is usually triggered when you render `<fa-icon>` component with `icon` property set to `null` or `undefined` (e.g. if you use async pipe or bind the specific icon to the property from response, etc). I guess the best way is to put a breakpoint on where the error is thrown and check the async stack trace to figure out which where exactly the `fa-icon` component is misused.

Comment: I got my issue. There was import missing for an icon.

Comment: @AmbujKhanna Can you please help on this? Which import did you miss? It will save my day.

Comment: @ChiragPatel As i mentioned above.. only icon import was missing. I was using multiple icons but I missed to import one of that icon and due which I was facing issue.